# PYTHON: How do I use BeautifulSoup to parse a table into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, seaborn

I am trying to scrape the CDC website for the data of the last 7 days reported cases for COVID-19.
https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#cases_casesinlast7days
I've tried to find the table, by name, id, class, and it always returns as none type. When I print the data scraped, I cant manually locate the table in the html either. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Once the data is imported, I need to populate a pandas dataframe to later use for graphing purposes, and export the data table as a csv.

Comment: for extra information, it appears that the table is generated in javascript so selemium will need to be used to get this data

Comment: what Taylor says is right. Additionally, I see that there is a button "download" on your website, so you might just try that (with selenium)

Answer (score 1):

You might as well request data from the API directly (check out Network tab in your browser while refreshing the page):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


endpoint = "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/COVIDData/getAjaxData"
data = requests.get(endpoint, params={"id": "US_MAP_DATA"}).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["US_MAP_DATA"])
```

---

[image]

---

#### EDIT: Trying to make this answer more general and useful.

> How did you discern that this was how to parse the data?

Firstly, you need to *inspect* the page (Ctrl + Shift + I) and navigate to *network* tab:

[image]

---

Secondly, you need to *refresh* the page to record network activity.

*Where to look?*

[image]

Check *XHR* to limit number of records (1);

Look through the records by clicking on them (2) and check their preview responses (3) to find out if it's the data you need.

---

It doesn't always work but when it does, parsing data from API directly is so much easier than writing scrapers via requests / bs4 / selenium etc and should be the first choice.

Comment: Wow! Worked like a charm! Its possible my assignment intended for me to use beautiful soup but this solution is far more fast and effective then selenium and a chromium executable. How did you discern that this was how to parse the data?

Comment: Thank you! Very thorough explanation